# Put numbers from a TSV file into an Array

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a TSV file with one column in it. In that column are a bunch of numbers. The column has a header.

What is the most efficient way to get all of the numbers in that column into one array? (say like 2,000,000 numbers).

Example data:

```
income
2000\n
80000\n
50000\n
30000\n
```

I have tried:

```
File.readlines(path)[1..-1].collect{|salary| salary.gsub("\n",'')}
```

I want to have the following output:

```
[2000,80000,50000,30000]
```

What I have works but I'm not sure it is the most efficient because I would be reading a million rows into memory.

Comment: How about some code of what you've already tried?

Comment: We need to see sample data, and an example of your desired output, along with code showing what you've already tried.

Comment: You need these numbers to be "numbers" (Fixnum class) or can they be String?

Comment: That's not a TSV (tab-separated value) file. It's a simple text file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, which may be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSV to do this, and it's really easy because you only have one column.

```
require 'csv'
CSV.read("/path/to/file.tsv").flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
array = []
File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
  next if $. == 1
  line.chomp!
  array << line if line > ''
end

p array
```

Which returns `array` as:

```
["2000", "80000", "50000", "30000"]
```

However, that is hardly a scalable solution. Depending on your machine you could run out of memory and take the app to a crawl. Instead, I'd strongly suggest using a simple database to store the values, and then operate on it. Databases are designed for this sort of purpose and can be extremely fast. I recommend using the [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) gem for that.

`$.` is a special variable that is used to track the row number of the last read file, so, as `foreach` passes lines into the block, `$.` will increment. That makes skipping a particular line easy.

```
  array << line if line > ''
```

is used to avoid appending empty/blank lines if the input file contains a trailing/terminating line-end.